# DocuSign Branding

Tags: docusignapi, branding

We want to create new DocuSign brand using DocuSign REST API and also want to set new brand profile as default for Send/Sign. We are able to create new brand using REST API, but we cannot set it default. We did not find any option in API to create/set brand to default. Could anyone help how we can create/set brand as default.

[DocuSign REST API](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Upload%20Brand%20Profiles.htm%3FTocPath%3DREST%2520API%2520References%7C_____17)

Thanks,
Jigar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **cannot currently** set the default brand using the REST API, but you **can** specify a per-Envelope brandId when sending.

NodeJS Example:

```
var envDef = new docusign.EnvelopeDefinition();

// Here is where you'll set the brandId, after creating your Envelope Definition
envDef.setBrandId('...');

// ... additional Envelope creation steps here

envelopesApi.createEnvelope('account_id', envDef, null, function (err, envelopeSummary, response) {
  if (err) {
    return next(err);
  }
  console.log('EnvelopeSummary', envelopeSummary);
});
```

See https://github.com/docusign/docusign-rest-recipes/blob/node-sdk/request_sig_via_email/request_sig_via_email.js#L93 for an example of basic sending.

Comment: the explanation and the code provided is not really helpful

Comment: Thanks for the answer..!  Yes Same we are doing currently..!

Comment: @thegio I added a link to the NodeJS example code where you'll only need to add the `.setBrandId` line to get a working example. What else might be helpful?